# PHP uploading CSV file and using first line as the KEYS instead of 0,1,2

Tags: php, csv, file

I am working on a CSV file upload function. The whole script is working fine and the way I am doing it is by eliminating the first line of the CSV file which is the heading and then using the data only to insert into the database. However, this adds a restriction for the CSV to be sorted always. I need to accept unsorted CSV too. For example, if a column `name` is in second column and of the CSV file then the array index becomes `$arr[1]`. Currently, I am using `$arr[1]` for inserting the values in the database and performing operations. This is bad. If the user uploads an unsorted CSV where `name` is in 4th column and say `phone` is in 2nd column where earlier I expected the name to be, then this will disrupt the whole operation. Therefore, how can I use the first heading line and use them as a key like `$arr['name']` for performing the required operations?

My current code:

```
$csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
fgetcsv($csvFile);

$arr = [];
while($data = fgetcsv($csvFile, 100, ",")){      
  $arr['id'] = $data[0]; // WANT TO USE $data['id'] FROM CSV FILE's FIRST LINE
  $arr['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[1])); // WANT TO USE $data['date'] FROM CSV FILE's FIRST LINE
  $arr['stock'] = $data[2]; // WANT TO USE $data['stock'] FROM CSV FILE's FIRST LINE
  $arr['price'] = $data[3]; // WANT TO USE $data['price'] FROM CSV FILE's FIRST LINE
  $ar[] = $arr;
}

fclose($csvFile);
```

How can I get the keys from the file and use it here in the code above?

**UPDATE**

I see that if I store the keys in array and print it like this

```
$csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$getFileKeys = fgetcsv($csvFile); // STORED KEYS IN ARRAY
fgetcsv($csvFile);
print_r($getFileKeys);
```

then I get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => date
    [2] => stock_name
    [3] => price
)
```

I need to write logic in such a way that if I have 4 variables one for each of the element above, then no matter if the index changes for any element, the variable will receive the same value dynamically.

Comment: Use `array_combine` to combine your array of keys, and the array of current line data you just read via fgetcsv.

Comment: @CBroe I am not sure about `array_combine` doing the job here as I need to loop through the list of the data and insert them in the database too. The accepted answer does the job. Please take a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure it would do the job. Once you prepared your data array, so that the right values _are_ under the right keys, you can access them via those keys to put them into your SQL query resp. bind them to the corresponding placeholder.

Comment: @CBroe if you could write a working answer using `array_combine` like Redstar Entertainment did, that would be easier to understand and I would be grateful.

Comment: `$arr = array_combine($getFileKeys, $data);` - that should get you the column values under the correct keys. That would be the original column values, of course - so you would have to do any manipulation that you need to do, afterwards. But at that point you _know_ the key under which the value is stored already - so you can simply do `$arr['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr['date']));` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got the keys inside `$getFileKeys` variable you can simply use a for loop to loop through the array of keys and dynamically assign the indexes based upon the field.

```
$getFileKeys = fgetcsv($csvFile);

$keys = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($getFileKeys); $i++){
  if($getFileKeys[$i] == 'id'){
    $keys['id'] = $i;
  }else if($getFileKeys[$i] == 'date'){
    $keys['date'] = $i;
  }else if($getFileKeys[$i] == 'stock_name'){
    $keys['stock'] = $i;
  }else if($getFileKeys[$i] == 'price'){
    $keys['price'] = $i;
  }
}

while($getData = fgetcsv($csvFile, 100, ",")){
  $arr['id'] = $getData[$keys['id']];
  $arr['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($getData[$keys['date']]));
  $arr['stock'] = trim($getData[$keys['stock']]);
  $arr['price'] = $getData[$keys['price']];
  $ar[] = $arr;
}
```

The `$keys` array now dynamically stores the indexes for each key. Therefore, this now sorts the CSV file no matter at what order which column is placed in.

Answer (score -1):

You could make variables out of the first line, so that you can call them by her name.

```
$exampleLine=[
  'id' => 1
  'date' => '2022-07-01'
  'stock_name' => 'stock_name'
  '3' => 'price'
];
foreach($exampleLine as $name){
   $$name=$name;
 }
```

This will give you the variables with appropriate content, so that $id contains 1, $date '2022-07-01' and so on.

to prevent different spellings, you could still use `lcfirst` and `trim`.

[PHP-Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: That's not what I was looking for.

Comment: Please take a look at the accepted answer. That will help you in future too. :)